# Why does print "\\" only print out a single backslash?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider the following Python 2.7 code:

```
 print "\\"
```

Expected result: `\\`

Actual result: `\`

Why does Python only print out a single backslash?

Comment: To get the intended result, you can put `r` before the string, which disables escape characters: `r"\\"`

Answer (score 9):

It's because `\` is the escape character, it escape sequences like newlines and carriage returns. To print out two you can do:

```
print "\\\\"
```

Or:

```
print r"\\"
```

`r` prefix tells to ignore escape characters.